# How to redirect a page with a query string to the homepage?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Recently I redesigned my site let's say http://www.sitename.com/ .

Before the redesign, the homepage url was something like this: http://www.sitename.com/default.asp?id=1&lg=1

Old pages had also weird query strings and they are not relevant any more, so, I want to redirect everything that begins with default.asp to the homepage.

```
RewriteRule default\.asp.* \
```

alternatively

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^default.asp?id=1&lg=1$ [NC]
RewriteRule http://www.sitename.com/ http://www.sitename.com/? [R=301,L]
```

This is the closest I have got so far, but I am pretty sure its wrong. 
Can you help?

Update: This is my whole .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule default\.asp.* /? 
</IfModule> 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 

# END WordPress
```

I have tried putting my rule at the top and at the bottom, (no luck). Should I embed it somehow on the other rule?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with what you have written so far? Also, I am no expert at .htaccess files but, shouldn't the last slash be the other kind of slash? `/`

Comment: It's clearly wrong, because it fails :) as far as the slash... I have no idea. I'm trying to modify other examples to my needs but this is the first time I touch .htaccess in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 

# redirect /default.asp to landing page
RewriteRule default\.asp$ /? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . index.php [L] 

</IfModule>    
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Yep. this worked. I didn't expect it but NC,R=301 made all the difference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) site, if you set up the rule like this

```
RewriteRule default\.asp.* /?
```

it should work.

Here is the reference for how you can replace query strings in the rewrite:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

> Modifying the Query String
>
> By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can,
>   however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query
>   string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string
>   to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the
>   query string. **When you want to erase an existing query string, end the
>   substitution string with just a question mark.** To combine new and old
>   query strings, use the [QSA] flag.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, try this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule default\.asp.*$ /? [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 

# END WordPress
```

Note the `[L]` at the end of `RewriteRule default\.asp.*$ /? [L]` which terminates the rewriting process when that match is found. See [L flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

If you don't include the L flag, then the process will continue with the rest of the rules in your `.htaccess` until it reaches the end with no matches or until it matches one with the L flag. Think of it like a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement, which needs a `break` in each case or else it continues to the next case, if it helps you.

Comment: Based on your tool it should work, yes. But I think it conflicts with the rest of my htaccess:
`# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule default\.asp.* /? 
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

I tried putting my rule on top.. putting it on bottom.. I dont have any other idead.

Comment: idead = ideas. I apologise for the messy code, I'll edit my initial post to make it more readable. The reference might have the answer, but it's kind of too advanced - I don't understand what I'm reading :S

Comment: Updated answer, please check it out.

Comment: On the tool you mentioned it works great, and the logic is sound. But it doesn't work on my site, damn it and I'm cracking my head.

Comment: Make sure you are restarting your server, or whatever it is that you have to do for changes to `.htaccess` to take effect. I'm off, will check again tomorrow. Καλημέρα

Comment: Rebooted the server, but nothing happened. He ignored me... I'll bug my hosting support. Thanks for the help, I'll let you know how it went. Καλημέρα to you, too! Or Καληνύχτα ;)

Answer (score 0):

**default.asp** is a filename you need to match against it using %{REQUEST_URI} variable. it's not part of querystring. To redirect requested URIs that contain **default.asp** ,you can use the following :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /default\.asp [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://sitename.com/? [R,L]
```